# Why is there a unique $a$ s.t. $f(x)-f(0)\sim ax$ but there are infinite $a$ s.t. $f(x)\sim f(0)+ax$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ a function that is $\mathcal C^1(\mathbb R)$. Why is there a unique $a\in\mathbb R$ such that $$f(x)-f(0)\sim_0 ax$$ but for all $a\in\mathbb R$ we have $f(x)\sim_0 f(0)+ax$ ?

I mean, why an equivalent of $f(x)-f(0)$ of the form $ax$ is unique where as an equivalent of $f(x)$ of the form $f(0)+ax$ is not unique ?

Comment: How do you define $\sim_0$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: $f\sim_0 g$ if $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f(x)-f(0)\sim_0ax$, then$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{ax}=1,$$which is equivalent to the assertion that $a=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}(=f'(0))$. So, $a$ is unique, since the limit of a function at a point, if it exists, is unique.

On the other hand, asserting that $f(x)\sim_0f(0)+ax$ means that$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{f(0)+ax}=1.$$But, unless $f(0)=0$, this limit is $\frac{f(0)}{f(0)}=1$, and therefore it does not depend on the choice of $a$.

---

From an informal point of view:

- The assertion $f(x)-f(0)\sim_0ax$ means that $f(x)-f(0)$ and $ax$ have the same tangent line at $(0,0)$. But $ax$ is its own tangent line and therefore its slope can only be the slope of the tangent line of the graph of $f(x)-f(0)$ at $(0,0)$.
- On the other hand, if $f(0)\neq0$, then both $f(x)$ and $f(0)+ax$ are different from $0$ at $0$ and then the assertion $f(x)\sim_0f(0)+ax$ simply means that both functions take the same value at $0$. Which they do, whatever the value of $a$ may be.

The bottom line is: $f(x)\sim_0g(x)$ is a stronger statement when $f(0)=g(0)=0$ than when $f(0)=g(0)\neq0$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In fact my problem was not in the proof, but conceptually. I have problem to understand why it is the case (despite the fact that I can prove it).

Comment: @MathBeginner I've edited my answer.